# How to stop NioProcessor logging?

Tags: java, logging

I'm seeing the logging come out , but have no idea how to stop

```
2021-12-30 11:36:48.585  INFO 20114 --- [NioProcessor-19] o.a.mina.filter.logging.LoggingFilter    : CLOSED
2021-12-30 11:36:48.590  INFO 20114 --- [NioProcessor-21] o.a.mina.filter.logging.LoggingFilter    : CREATED
2021-12-30 11:36:48.590  INFO 20114 --- [NioProcessor-21] o.a.mina.filter.logging.LoggingFilter    : OPENED
2021-12-30 11:36:48.593  INFO 20114 --- [NioProcessor-46] o.a.mina.filter.logging.LoggingFilter    : CLOSED
2021-12-30 11:36:48.596  INFO 20114 --- [NioProcessor-48] o.a.mina.filter.logging.LoggingFilter    : CREATED
```

Comment: I don't think we can answer this yet.  We need to know 1) what application is creating these log entries, 2) what logging package is it using, 3) how the logging is configured in / by the app.  Please find that information and **edit it into the question**.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.